# Django REST framwork mongoengine ValueError: The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I'm working a project, and use Django REST framework and mongo engine, and I'm confused a question two days, and the detail see below:

```
class Jvv(EmbeddedDocument):
    unit = fields.StringField()
    unitValue = fields.IntField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'imagerecognition'


class ImageRecognition(Document):
    imageUrl = fields.StringField(default='', max_length=100)
    createTime = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    ddPercent = fields.FloatField(required=False, default='')
    jvv = fields.ListField(fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(Jvv))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.imageUrl

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'imagerecognition'
```

then the serializer.p document is :

```
class JvvSerializer(mongoserializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Jvv
       fields = '__all__'


class ImageUrlSerializer(mongoserializers.DocumentSerializer):
    jvv = JvvSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ImageRecognition
        fields = ('imageUrl', 'createTime', 'ddPercent', 'jvv')
```

and the views.py content is below:

```
class ImageUrlSave(views.APIView):
    def get(self,  request, *args, **kwargs):
        imgs = ImageRecognition.objects(imageUrl='白菜')
        serializer = ImageUrlSerializer(imgs, many=True)
        ImageRecognition(imageUrl='土豆', ddPercent=8.22, jvv={'unit':'m', 'unitValue':12}).save()
        data = serializer.data
        return Response({
            'msg': 'SUCCESS',
            'code_status': 1000,
            'result': data
        })
```

the question is the mongodatabases have been completed, I want to take some data from it, but when I runserver, it shows 
    raise ValueError("The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict'")
    ValueError: The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict', how can I handle this problem, and I am Looking forward to get answer. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question to post the whole error message with full traceback please.

Comment: Does it help to change `jvv={'unit':'m', 'unitValue':12}` to `jvv=[{'unit':'m', 'unitValue':12}]` ?